# nginx fails to start - troubleshoot

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, systemd, nginx-location, journal

I have a simple nginx config that is syntactically correct. I install nginx using chef and the chef script works fine.

But as I check status of nginx , I see it is in failed state. If I reload nginx , it again goes in failed state. ***journalctl -xn*** also doesnt give much of error except :

```
    [root@localhost vagrant]# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Wed 2016-10-26 04:28:18 UTC, end at Wed 2016-10-26 04:45:00 UTC. --
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -s, --signal <sig>     send specified signal
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -q, --queue <sig>      use sigqueue(2) rather than kill(2)
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -p, --pid              print pids without signaling them
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -l, --list [=<signal>] list signal names, or convert one to a name
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -L, --table            list signal names and numbers
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -h, --help     display this help and exit
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -V, --version  output version information and exit
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: For more details see kill(1).
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
[root@localhost vagrant]#
```

nginx -t is successful and I see nothing in /var/log/nginx/errors.log

Is there any other way to troubleshoot exactly why this fails ?

Both systemctl status nginx.service  gives:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# systemctl status nginx.service
nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-10-26 04:45:00 UTC; 9h ago
  Process: 17003 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16999 ExecStart=/opt/nginx-1.10.1/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16998 ExecStartPre=/opt/nginx-1.10.1/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16999 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -s, --signal <sig>     send specified signal
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -q, --queue <sig>      use sigqueue(2) rather than kill(2)
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -p, --pid              print pids without signaling them
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -l, --list [=<signal>] list signal names, or convert one to a name
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -L, --table            list signal names and numbers
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -h, --help     display this help and exit
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: -V, --version  output version information and exit
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain kill[17003]: For more details see kill(1).
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 26 04:45:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

systemctl cat nginx.service gives :

```
[root@virsinplatformapi02 sysadmin]# systemctl cat nginx.service
Unknown operation 'cat'.
```

I cd cd /lib/systemd/system and do cat on nginx.service:

```
[root@virsinplatformapi02 system]# cat nginx.service
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/opt/nginx-1.10.1/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/opt/nginx-1.10.1/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
```

**If I do a echo $MAINPID , I get nothing.**

Comment: Looks like you have error not in your nginx config, but in your nginx systemd unit. Add `systemctl status nginx.service` and `systemctl cat nginx.service` please.

Comment: @HardyRust - check edit

Comment: Looks like, for some reason `$MAINPID` is epmty when killing. Please, check again, `systemctl cat nginx.service` should print out the unit itself.

Comment: @HardyRust - Check Edit

Answer (score 0):

That is not very good unitfile. Type is not set and defaults to `simple`, while you want to you `forking` for nginx. That may be the reason for the wrong `$MAINPID` value. Try to use [official unit](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/):

```
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/opt/nginx-1.10.1/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/opt/nginx-1.10.1/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should just add it to `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` - that directory it intended for administrator-created units, and has priority.